# How to stop loading of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

How to stop loading of iframe when the response for first request come.i have include this but this will load complete url  which i don't want.i only want to set cookies from  first request response 
This is cross domain request

i have tried JSON get request but it is not setting cookies in my browser whihc i can use in next request.

please help us

Comment: $.getJSON("http://www.google.com",
  function(data) {
  alert(data);
  });
  }

Comment: two things: edit your question posting the code that you have tried, and go accept some anwers.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by the  `window.stop():`

try

```
window.frames[0].stop()
```

Comment: thanks but how i will detect when the response of first request comes .because  i need to call window.frames[0].stop() when the response of first request come

Comment: can any one please tell me when the iframe readystate changed to loading when the response of first request comes